# Configuring WPS Workbench to run an Autoexec on startup

Tags: eclipse, sas

Does anyone have any experience configuring the WPS engine to run, essentially an autoexec.sas on startup?

I cannot find any documentation on how to implement this feature for WPS.  I see that they have the option available to set, but I cannot find where to put the file or what to name it.

http://www.teamwpc.co.uk/docs/WPS-Core-Quick-Ref.xls  -- shows that they have the Autoexec option enabled, but when I run proc options there's no value in it.

If WPS doesn't have this working, does eclipse have the ability to run a script on startup?'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah!  After a little more careful googling, and some reading between lines of the google results I figured this out.

All you have to do to get the autoexec to run is name the file autoexec.sas, just as in SAS, and then place it in the root directory of the WPS workbench.

Comment: Also, for another possibility you can do the following:

To set the autoexec up you need to do the following :
 
Window => Preferences => Expand WPS=> Select Startup Options => Add => Select AUTOEXEC => Enter 'Fullpathname'

Answer (score 0):

I have found that WPS mirrors the sas command.  I set up a shortcut to WPS that says the same as for sas

```
C:\program files\...\workbench.exe  -autoexec "autoexecfilename" etc>
```

In this I also use the "start in" to point to a directory.  In my autoexec I put 
`libname x '.';`  and that assigns the X libname to the specific directory I choose.  This allows for one shortcut in each directory, and X is in THAT directory.